# This is my assumption about improper integral. Is this correct?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $p$ be a real number. I think:
$$q\in \mathbb R^+ \quad \text{iff} \quad \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{e^{qx}} dx<+\infty$$
because $\frac{x^p}{e^{qx}}$ converges to $0$ very quickly when $q>0$.

Is this right? If so, how can I prove?
I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As soon as $p>-1$ and $q>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^p e^{-qx}\,dx = \frac{p!}{q^{p+1}} $$
by the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @ciatina: because in a right neighbourhood of the origin $x^p e^{-qx}$ behaves like $x^p$, and $x^p$ is integrable in a right neighbourhood of the origin iff $p>-1$.

Comment: Okay, got it. But I think, for example let $p=-\frac{3}{2}$ and then it also converges because $Γ(p)=\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{π}$ which contradicts $p>-1$.

Comment: @ciatina: the $\Gamma$ function is well-defined for negative parameters too by analytic continuation, but that does not mean that the given integral is convergent. For $p=-\frac{3}{2}$, it is not, for instance.

Comment: Hmm...okay, I think I need much more information about the Gamma I'll google it. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

> Near $0$

the integrand function is equivalent to

$$x^p $$ since $e^{qx}$ goes to $1$.
thus it converges iff $-p <1$.

> Near $+\infty $.

if $q <0$, the integrand goes to $+\infty $ and the integral diverges.

If $q=0$, it diverges cause $-p <1$

If $q>0$, we have

$$\lim_{+\infty}x^{\color {red}{2}}x^pe^{-qx}=0$$

because as you said, the exponential is Faster.
thus for $x $ great enough,

$$x^{\color {red}{2}}x^pe^{-qx}<\color {green}{1}$$
and
$$\frac {x^p}{e^{qx}}<\frac{\color {green}{1}}{x^{\color {red}{2}} }$$

the integral converges by comparison.

> Your generalized integral converges if only if $p>-1$ and $q>0$.